# How do I upload photos to django media root directory using a completely different python script?

Tags: django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am using django 1.9 and I have created a website with it. The database I am using with django is MySQL (`django.db.backends.mysql`). Everything in the website works fine. I can retrieve, delete and put files in the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory using the website's interface that I have successfully designed.

Now, I am making a desktop app version of the website. The whole thing is created using python. I can connect to the same database as my website using the python program and I want my python program to be able to upload images to the mysql database in a way so that they are stored in the django `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. Also, I want to be able to retrieve images from the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory so that I can save it in the same directory as my python program.

How do I upload and download media files from the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory of django assuming that it is not *locally hosted* but hosted **on the internet** using a python script?

Answer (score 0):

Any file you upload is stored in MEDIA_ROOT directory. When you Look at database structure, you wiil see django keep string field with file path relatively MEDIA_ROOT.

It is bad idea manage database data outside django application, from you remote application by example.

I would extend server-side web application by uploading/downloading service with controlling user permissions. There is excellent rest-framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ that will help you up usefull service for accessing and manipulation of data outside django application.